# How to fix the error <HttpError 404 "Requested entity was not found.">

Tags: python, google-sheets, http-error

After insert data to google sheet via python, I want to try and clear those data in google sheet and came into an error

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/Master/values/Master%21A3%3AZ:clear?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.">
```

I don't know what happen since I followed instruction from quickstart python page https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/clear

here is the code I got so far

```
def remove():
    service=get_service()

    sheet_name = 'Master'
    range_values = sheet_name + '!A3:Z'

    clear_values_request_body = {
    # TODO: Add desired entries to the request body.
    }

    request = service.spreadsheets().values().clear(spreadsheetId=sheet_name, range=range_values, body=clear_values_request_body)
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)
```

I can't detect the error , have i done something wrong?

Comment: i made the same silly mistake - in my case, I wrapped it in a Function and kept sending the query as the `spreadsheetId`.

it seems that you too are using the wrong `spreadsheetId`  - it's **NOT** supposed to be `sheet_name`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library instead which would help you tremendously. I'm the author of Python Sheetfu (https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu).

There are other libraries that you should also look at too, gspread and pygsheet to name them, that would help.